# How do I install and configure Generic Mapping Tools (GMT)?

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I am using Ubuntu 19.10.

I tried to install GMT. I don't understand how I do next step even if there is [building/GMT](https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/gmt/blob/master/BUILDING.md).

I ran terminal in home/user_name. I carried out codes until title of **[Getting GMT source codes](https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/gmt/blob/master/BUILDING.md)**.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake libcurl4-gnutls-dev libnetcdf-dev

sudo apt-get install gdal-bin libgdal-dev libfftw3-dev libpcre3-dev liblapack-dev libblas-dev libglib2.0-dev ghostscript

sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick ffmpeg

sudo apt-get install xdg-utils

sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick

sudo apt-get install python-sphinx
```

That is why I stopped to install it.

Should I go on at for next step at *home/user_name* as follows?

```
git clone https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/gmt
wget ftp://ftp.soest.hawaii.edu/gshhg/gshhg-gmt-2.3.7.tar.gz
wget ftp://ftp.soest.hawaii.edu/dcw/dcw-gmt-1.1.4.tar.gz
for i in *.tar.gz; do tar -xvzf $i; done
```

Next process for title title of **[Configuring](https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/gmt/blob/master/BUILDING.md)**

I think code shoul be below but I am not sure where to use this code. Inside /home/user_name/gmt/cmake ?

Should I use `cd cmake` and then below code?

```
cp ./cmake/ConfigUserTemplate.cmake ./cmake/ConfigUser.cmake
```

It is probably too easy to build and configure by this point but I failed. Help me, please.

Comment: Just without `cd cmake`. You can use a graphical file explorer too.

Comment: 'gmt' not found, but can be installed with `sudo apt install gmt`. If I do it, it install version 5.4.5.

Comment: I did the rest but I have a still problem. Any ideas?